# New app release not going through the play console review

Tags: google-play-console

I am a new at this and I have been trying to update my new release APK but when the Play store reviews it they rejected with an screenchot of the first APK instead of the new one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if your app was ever rejected, sometime it may appear in Play Console [Publishing overview] with "Changes you make won't be sent for review automatically" and [Send for review] button.
Press [Send for review] button to let it be reviewed. Hope this is helpful.